# Rspec method create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, methods, rspec

i try to test method create in my controller:

```
def create
    @fund = Fund.new({started_at: Date.strptime(params[:fund].delete(:started_at), '%m/%d/%Y')}.merge(fund_params))
    if @fund.save
      flash[:alert] = "Fund #{@fund.name} saved!"
      redirect_to funds_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Fund #{@fund.name} could not be saved"
      render :edit
    end
end
```

file spec:

```
it 'Can create a new fund' do
    fund = FactoryGirl.create(:fund)
    post :create
    expect(response).to redirect_to(funds_path)
end
```

And show this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
```

The error is in this line, for the method 'delete':

```
 @fund = Fund.new({started_at: Date.strptime(params[:fund].delete(:started_at),...
```

i don't know how solve this problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, that's because `params[:fund]` is `nil`. Try to send the proper parameters to the `create` action:

```
post :create, fund: { add_here_needed_params_for_this_action }
```

Example:

```
post :create, fund: { started_at: Date.today }
```

Comment: Yes, it's a great advice, I'll try it